# How to use multiple frames for pages

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I want to create simple navigation for my game. What I do is I create empty movie clips in different frames in my .fla file and in.as file add child to that movie clip, but I get error **Line 24  1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addChild through a reference with static type Class.**

Here's my .as file code:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.events.Event;

public class KingOfMath extends MovieClip  {
    public function KingOfMath():void  {

        //Create load progress text format
        var loadProgressFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        loadProgressFormat.align = "center";
        loadProgressFormat.bold = true;
        loadProgressFormat.font = "Arial";
        loadProgressFormat.size = 16;

        //Create load progress text field
        var loadProgressText:TextField = new TextField();
        loadProgressText.defaultTextFormat = loadProgressFormat;
        loadProgressText.width = 550;
        loadProgressText.x = 0;
        loadProgressText.y = 350;
        loadScreen.addChild(loadProgressText);

        //Create progress bar mechanism
        stop();

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loadProgress);

        function loadProgress(event:Event):void  {
            //Get bytes loaded and bytes total
            var gameBytesLoaded:int = root.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
            var gameBytesTotal:int = root.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;

            //Convert to kilobytes
            var gameKilobytesLoaded:int = gameBytesLoaded / 1024;
            var gameKilobytesTotal:int = gameBytesLoaded / 1024;

            //Show progress text
            loadProgressText.text = "Loading: " + gameKilobytesLoaded + "K/" + gameKilobytesTotal + "K";

            if(gameKilobytesLoaded >= gameKilobytesTotal)  {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loadProgress);
                gotoAndStop(2);
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is `loadScreen`? The error says it is a type of something, instead of an instance.

Comment: loadScreen is empyt movie clip created manualy in .fla file

Comment: This means you didn't add it to your `KingOfMath` movieclip in that .fla. If so, you would have to assign it an instance name, which you then use in the problem code.

Comment: Well I don't get any error but when I add something to that movie clip as a child I can't see anything on the stage.

Comment: I have changed screen movie clip size to 1x1px and it works right now